# Is there something different about .net 4 that makes .ASPXAUTH cookie disappear?

Tags: cookies, .net-4.0, forms-authentication, .aspxauth

I am experiencing pretty much identical behavior to [ASP.NET MVC 4 cookie disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343073/asp-net-mvc-4-cookie-disappears) .

To confirm that it is .net 4 I created a new, empty .net 4 web application that uses Forms authentication. (I have several .net 3.5 sites that use the same Forms authentication settings just fine.) I added a Global.asax file and set a breakpoint in the Application_BeginRequest method. I see the ASPXAUTH cookie come in on the request. However, by the time it gets to the EndRequest method the cookie is no longer there. Has anyone seen this behavior in .net 4? It doesn't happen in 3.5 so there must be some change to default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after putting in the magic words to Google (I tried Open Sesame and everything) it revealed this previous StackOverflow question: [Asp.Net Forms Authentication SSO between 4.0 and 2.0 applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164178/asp-net-forms-authentication-sso-between-4-0-and-2-0-applications)

This eventually did the trick. I say eventually because I had modified a few of the web.config settings for both my login application as well as my new 4.0 app and it took me a bit to discover that I had added Decrytion="3DES" to the v4 app but no longer had that in my login app. Ah, .net, what a tangled wwweb we weave...